# Criteria api join after fetch throws Invalid path error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have three simple entities:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Subject> subjects;
}

@Entity
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Topic> topics;
}


@Entity
public class Topic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

and I use criteria api to obtain the data. I need subjects to be pre-fetched.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Category> cq = cb.createQuery(Category.class);
Root<Category> root = cq.from(Category.class);
cq.select(root);
Join subjects = (Join) root.fetch("subjects");
Join topics = subjects.join("topics");
Predicate predicate1 = cb.equal(topics.get("name"), "topic2");
cq.where(predicate1);

List<Category> resultList = this.em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

But I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias2.name' [select generatedAlias0 from entities.Category as generatedAlias0 inner join fetch generatedAlias0.subjects as generatedAlias1 where generatedAlias2.name=:param0]
```

Can anybody tell me what it is the problem. By the way, the error won't appear if I use join instead of fetch

Answer (score 2):

I met exactly the same problem with you. Through the sql query, the last join statement was missing. As your exception told you, the *generatedAlias2* was never been aliased at all before using it.

And my solution is simple and it works. 
**Convert fetch to Join at the very least**.

Here is an example

```
Fetch subjects = root.fetch("subjects");
Join topics = (Join) subjects.fetch("topics");
Predicate predicate1 = cb.equal(topics.get("name"), "topic2");
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution works. But it will fetch all data of Topic, too.

The same query in JPQL would looks like this one:

```
Select c from Category c
join fetch c.subjects s
join s.topics t 
where t.name = 'topic2'
```

And it will work without any problem. So why the CriteriaQuery behaves different?

Comment: I don't know why. It seems to be a bug.

Comment: I have faced the same issue in my code, any idea if a newer version solves this issue?
I am running spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE with Hibernate core 5.4.10.Final